# Access Control Allow Origin is no present on signalr 2.0 cross domain cors

Tags: javascript, asp.net, heroku, ember.js, signalr

I have a Asp.Net Signalr application hosted on `mokey.gear.host`, and an emberjs app hosted on `frozen-brook-1900.herokuapp.com`.

Everything works fine locally, and I can communicate my client app to signalr.
I can access `mokey.gear.host` deployed app through my local client application.
But when I deploy client to heroku it gives me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mokey.gear.host/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=…ame%22%3A%22game%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22lobby%22%7D%5D&_=1432319963807. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://frozen-brook-1900.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is my server configuration:

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{

    var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
    {
        AllowAnyHeader = true,
        AllowAnyMethod = true
    };
    corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://frozon-brook-1900.herokuapp.com");
    corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://192.168.56.103:4200");
    map.UseCors(new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider {
            PolicyResolver =
            r => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
        }
    });

    map.RunSignalR(config);
});
```

This is my client configuration:

`index.html`

```
<!--<script src="http://localhost:51614/signalr/hubs"></script>-->
<script src="http://mokey.gear.host/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

`hubs.js`

```
// $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:51614/signalr';
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://mokey.gear.host/signalr';

$.connection.hub.start({
  withCredentials: false
}).then(function() {
  console.log('connected');
  self.lobby.server.join();
});
```

You can visit my client app and see the error for yourself at: http://frozen-brook-1900.herokuapp.com/play

Comment: Did you set `frozen-brook-1900.herokuapp.com` in your `config/environment.js`? Check [this](http://emberjs.com/security/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736272/setting-cors-for-static-files-on-ember-cli-server)

Comment: I call `hub.start` at an initializer, strangely `config/environment` code isn't reached when the error occurs. @MilkyWayJoe

Comment: I think I misunderstood initially. I see that the error message is different now; no longer about CORS