# Ember.js deployment error with ember-cli-deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, amazon-s3, ember-cli

**Final Edit:** thanks to [Luke Melia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539147/ember-js-deployment-error-with-ember-cli-deploy?noredirect=1#comment58779392_35539147), I figured out that it was a fingerprinting issue. I needed to have it prepend my S3 URL to the vendor files. [These are the docs on it](http://ember-cli.com/ember-cli-deploy/docs/v0.5.x/fingerprinting/) for anyone who comes across my answer in the future.

### Original Question:

I've deployed my Ember app using the `ember-cli-deploy` [Lightning Strategy](http://ember-cli.com/ember-cli-deploy/docs/v0.5.x/lightning-strategy-examples/). Basically, instead of just moving the Ember assets to the Rails `public` folder, I'm storing the assets on S3 and using Redis to fetch the content. However, I'm still having issues.

**Edit:** Please look at my edits below. It looks like it's serving `index.html` instead of the assets. That is, when I looked at the Sources tab in the Chrome console and clicked on `vendor-*.js` file, it shows `index.html` instead of the correct JavaScript file.

#### Console errors:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'jQneD+vBDVT7ee1Z9kI1izwIriOTtrL9BSbgXhWAyiY='. The resource has been blocked.
GET http://my-url.com/assets/vendor-810b00597803ee384ddec79fd82e6983.js ## These are 422 Unprocessable Entity errors.
GET http://my-url.com/assets/my-app-e62bc38bf7f8222ada28c3610ca3fc0c.js ## These are 422 Unprocessable Entity errors.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/my-app-d27a867b5c015e75b8e2110796a9e504.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'jQneD+vBDVT7ee1Z9kI1izwIriOTtrL9BSbgXhWAyiY='. The resource has been blocked.
```

I'm mostly concerned about the 422 errors, though I'm not sure why it's still blocking the CSS files. (**Edit:** see my edits below to see why I think this is happening.)

#### package.js dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "active-model-adapter": "2.1.1",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.3.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "0.5.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-manifest": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-redis": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "0.2.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-ssh-tunnel": "0.2.2",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-materialize": "git://github.com/robbyoconnor/ember-cli-materialize.git#e39b833f1dfb66b342873d25d05fabcb17b59a3f",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.2.1",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-composability": "0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "^2.3.0",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-key-responder": "0.4.2",
    "ember-legacy-views": "0.2.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-modal-dialog": "0.8.3",
    "ember-new-computed": "1.0.3",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.0"
}
```

I had also tried to use `ember-cli-cors` as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681983/2258441), but that hadn't made a difference.

#### config/environment.js:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
      }
    },
    APP: {
    },
    contentSecurityPolicyHeader: 'Content-Security-Policy',
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://my-url.com",
      'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://my-url.com",
    }
  };

  return ENV;
};
```

#### CORS configuration on S3:

```
    <CORSConfiguration>
        <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>http://my-url.com/</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

### Edit 1:

I opened the files that had the 422 errors, and the Rails `production.log` said: `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript.` I wound up adding `protect_from_forgery except: :index` to my frontend controller, and now this is what pops up in my console:

#### Console errors:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'rmy5bIbd1VtZvKFFNrowA8t7HzdFGJzV5tOFMqMQ8yE='. The resource has been blocked.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/vendor-810b00597803ee384ddec79fd82e6983.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'rmy5bIbd1VtZvKFFNrowA8t7HzdFGJzV5tOFMqMQ8yE='. The resource has been blocked.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/visual-climate-d27a867b5c015e75b8e2110796a9e504.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'rmy5bIbd1VtZvKFFNrowA8t7HzdFGJzV5tOFMqMQ8yE='. The resource has been blocked.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://my-url.com/assets/visual-climate-e62bc38bf7f8222ada28c3610ca3fc0c.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'rmy5bIbd1VtZvKFFNrowA8t7HzdFGJzV5tOFMqMQ8yE='. The resource has been blocked.
```

### Edit 2:

I temporarily added `integrity=""` in my `index.html`, and it appears that it's replacing all of my asset files with `index.html`. I believe that's what's actually causing the problem.

### Edit 3:

I temporarily moved my assets to Rails' public folder, and the app works. It looks like there's something wrong with how to handles the asset files on S3. I'm adding my `deploy.js` file in case it's not configured correctly.

#### deploy.js:

```
module.exports = function(deployTarget) {
  var ENV = {};

  if (deployTarget === 'development-postbuild') {
    ENV.plugins = ['redis'];

    ENV.build = {
      environment: 'development'
    };

    ENV.redis = {
      keyPrefix: 'my-app',
      revisionKey: '__development__',
      allowOverwrite: true,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
      distDir: function(context) {
        return context.commandOptions.buildDir;
      }
    };
  }

  if (deployTarget === 'production') {
    ENV.build = {
      environment: 'production'
    };

    ENV.pipeline = {
      activateOnDeploy: true
    };

    ENV['ssh-tunnel'] = {
      username: process.env['SSH_USERNAME'],
      host: process.env['REDIS_HOST'],
      srcPort: process.env['REDIS_PORT']
    };

    ENV.redis = {
      keyPrefix: 'my-app',
      allowOverwrite: true,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: process.env['REDIS_PORT']
    };

    ENV.s3 = {
      accessKeyId: process.env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
      secretAccessKey: process.env['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],
      bucket: 'my_app_bucket',
      region: 'us-west-2'
    };
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

I used the same options that are used in [ember-deploy-demo](https://github.com/ghedamat/ember-deploy-demo) because it appears to be the same setup that I'm using.

Comment: Hi @NJP, you might start by bumping your ember-cli-sri to 2.1.0. I recently fixed some bugs that might lead to invalid hashes being generated.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't fix it, but it's good to know that there were bugfixes to one of the packages.

Comment: Sorry to start at the beginning, but after you run the `ember deploy production` are there files in S3/my_app_bucket on the amazon AWS web console?  And if you log into your redis server and run `redis>keys my-app*` do you have entries?

Comment: Do you have your "fingerprint" settings in ember-cli-build.js set to prepend your asset URLs with your S3 or Cloudfront domain?

Comment: That did it! I had a fingerprint setting set for development, but not production. Now it's working!